# Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String' WHEN NOT CONNECTING AS ROOT

Tags: c#, mysql, privileges, .net

I will start by saying that I know this exact question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141092/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-dbnull-to-type-system-string) but it was incorrectly marked as a duplicate question and never answered.

The first key point about this question is that the `InvalidCastExcpetion` is thrown, before attempting to use the return from the stored procedure. So all of the suggested solutions, which are to deal with that are not applicable. It fails on the line that executes the SQL command.

The second key point is that the exact same code works successfully when connecting as root but not when connecting as a different user. Therefore, it is not a problem with the code that can be solved with any of the previously given solutions.

Does anyone have any ideas why this would work for the root user but not for another and why the message in the exception has nothing to do with privileges? By the way, the user in question has execute privileges and can call this procedure from within MySQL Workbench.

I do not think the code is particularly relevant, given that it works for root but I am including it anyway.

My C# code is as follows:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(SqlConnectionString)) {
  using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    try {
      conn.Open();
      cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandText = @"open_application";
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?p_opr_id", organisationID);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?p_app_id", applicationID);
      MySqlParameter returnValue = new MySqlParameter();
      returnValue.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
      returnValue.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
      cmd.Parameters.Add(returnValue);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      //Deal with the return value
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      message = "Failed to record application opening: " + ex.Message;
    }
  }
}
```

The InvalidCastException is thrown from cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

The MySQL stored function is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `open_application` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `open_application`(p_opr_id int,  p_app_id int) RETURNS tinyint
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_opened int;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT opened FROM operator_application WHERE opr_id = p_opr_id AND app_id = p_app_id;

  OPEN cur;
  FETCH cur INTO v_opened;
  CLOSE cur;

  IF v_opened = 1 THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;

  UPDATE operator_application SET opened = 1 WHERE opr_id = p_opr_id AND app_id = p_app_id;

  RETURN 1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

** UPDATE **

I have rewritten the stored function as a stored procedure. Instead of using RETURN, I am using SELECT and then invoking the stored procedure using MySQLCommand.ExecuteScalar, instead of ExecuteNonQuery. It is now working. I still have no idea why it wasn't working as a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error you get does not represent the real problem.
There are two possible ways that InvalidCastException is raised while executing ADO command.

1. **Input parameter type missmatch**. If any of input parameter values (either organisationID or applicationID) cannot be converted to desired sql type the exception is raised
2. **Result/Output parameter type mismatch**. If value returned by sql function (or assigned to output parameter) cannot be converted to result type (Int32 in you case) the exception is raised

I suspect that when connecting as non-root user, access is denied to some table/view/cursor and your sql function raises error and no RETURN statement is executed. This way you will get NULL value in output parameter and the exception.
This is a blind guess but maybe there is problem with cursor rights (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155080/cursor-in-mysql-has-other-rights-than-user)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried using DEFINER=root and I am still getting the same error. Also, I do not understand why the access rights would be different when invoking the function in MySQL workbench vs. invoking it from a C# application. The user can successfully call the function in Workbench.

Comment: I have rewritten the stored function as a procedure, simply selecting what was the return value of the function. I am invoking it using ExecuteScalar and it is working. I am still baffled why this does not work with a function but at least I have been able to work around it.